# Eclipse runnable jar export exclude lombok with maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have a maven project which includes lombok for those handy lombok functions:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When i export the project using "Export" > "runnable JAR file" and pick option "copy required libraries into a sub-folder" the lombok-*.jar is always put in the "program_lib" folder.

I use scope test, but also tried provided, but the lombok jar still gets copied.

Strange thins is that junit with scope 'test' is not copied:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

That confused me a bit.

How can i keep using the export to runnable JAR function but exclude the lombok.jar?

Answer (score 0):

**You should use `provided` scope for Lombok** as lombok is basically hooking into the compilation process. You don't need it once the compilation happens.

**Eclipse probably does not understand the `provided` scope correctly. Use Maven command instead.**

Comment: I already tried scope provided like noted in my question. But thanks for the suggestion of using the maven command, but i rather would keep using the runnable jar export from eclipe, it always worked for me. Except this time...